# Hosting web api as webapp in azure along with VM in same data center

Tags: azure, networking, azure-web-app-service, lan

I have a VM running SQL Server in Azure East US2. I also hosted a webapi as azure web app. Connection string used in webapi is being routed through internet gateway right now. I want to ensure that both of these services are hosted on same data center so that they communicate over LAN instead of internet gateway.

I was trying to setup a VNET and when I tried adding this VNET to webapi, it asks to setup VPN gateway. Why do I need to setup VPN gateway, are they not aware of being on same data center. Can't they be put on LAN without setting up VPN.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy both your VM and your Web App in `Azure East US2` they land on the same geo-region. Please note that a lot of Azure Regions do have more than one facility (the thing you call Data Center), and you have no control over where exactly within a region (i.e. East US2) your resource will be deployed.

Now, if you want to talk to your SQL Server on an Azure VM from the Web App, you have to use [VNet integraton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). Because you are not deploying into a [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro), you have to [connect your web app to the VNet where your SQL Server is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). The way to do this is by **implicitly** utilising a [Point-to-Site VPN Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-classic-azure-portal) between your web app and your VNet.

Do not worry, the whole process is automated and you do not have to deal with certificates and certificate roll-over, but there is a need for VPN Gateway. That's way you are being asked for the VPN Gateway.

But you should really consider using Azure SQL DB instead an SQL Server on VM.